# Finding consecutive values in a string in R

Tags: r, string, sequence, stringr

I am trying to find 3 or more consecutive "a" within the last 10 letters of my data frame string. My data frame looks like this:

```
V1
aaashkjnlkdjfoin
jbfkjdnsnkjaaaas
djshbdkjaaabdfkj
jbdfkjaaajbfjna
ndjksnsjksdnakns
aaaandfjhsnsjna
```

I have written this code, however it just gets out the number of consecutive "a" within the whole string. However, I am wanting to do it so it only looks at the last 10 digits and then prints the string where the consecutive "a" are found. The code I have wrote is:

```
out: [1] 3
```

I am wanting my output to look like this:

```
jbfkjdnsnkjaaaas
djshbdkjaaabdfkj
jbdfkjaaajbfjna
```

Can anyone help

Comment: I would use substring to get the last 10 characters, then grepl to check for any aaa values within that substring.

Comment: Try `subset(df1, grepl("(a)\\1{2,}", substring(V1, nchar(V1)-9, nchar(V1))))`

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, you could do:

```
grep("(?=.{10}$).*?a{3,}", string, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
[1] "jbfkjdnsnkjaaaas" "djshbdkjaaabdfkj" "jbdfkjaaajbfjna"
```

---

```
string <- c("aaashkjnlkdjfoin", "jbfkjdnsnkjaaaas", "djshbdkjaaabdfkj", 
            "jbdfkjaaajbfjna", "ndjksnsjksdnakns", "aaaandfjhsnsjna")
```

If you have a dataframe and need tosubset it:

```
subset(df, grepl("(?=.{10}$).*?a{3}",V1, perl = TRUE))
                V1
2 jbfkjdnsnkjaaaas
3 djshbdkjaaabdfkj
4  jbdfkjaaajbfjna
```